# History Api (Kohana)

Tags: kohana

Есть ссылки вида

```
news/view/12/125
section/view/12
```

и т.д.

При переходе по страницам меняется содержимое блока с классом content

Когда отправляю запрос на страницу news/view/12/2323, возвращается вся страница начиная с доктайпа

Comment: На тот случай, если никто не придет и не напишет развернутый ответ:  
1. Делаем так, чтобы AJAX-запрос по тому же адресу отдавал только содержимое блока content.  
2. Прикручиваем js-обработчик на ссылку, который срабатывает на шаблон нужного адреса и загружает в блок .content все, что ему отдаст AJAX-запрос по этой ссылке.  
Если все это - незнакомые слова, то посмотрите jQuery.ajax и JSON. Правильный отлов ajax-запроса - по заголовкам, но можно просто добавлять ?ajax=true к ссылке и отслеживать по этому флагу.

Comment: отслеживать где? в контроллере или?

Comment: Да, в контроллере. При получении запроса проверяем, есть ли заголовок (или GET-параметр ajax), если есть - отдаем просто content (возможно, завернутый в json, ксли потребуется еще что-то передавать), если заголовка/флага нет - отдаем обычную страницу.

Comment: возможно, завернутый в json, ксли потребуется еще что-то передавать

можно подробнее.... что значит что-то передавать?

Comment: Может возникнуть ситуация, когда вам надо передать клиенту (пользователю) не только содержимое статьи, но и, скажем, заголовок статьи и комментарии к ней. В этом случае передавать целиком большие куски html будет некрасиво (и может попортить систему шаблонов), самым верным (и наименее затратным по объему данных) было бы переслать _массив_ со всем необходимым. Этого можно достичь, упаковав в массив в JSON-формате - в результате и система шаблонов не задействована вообще никак, и передается все за один раз, и минимум байтов потрачено.

Comment: а в kohana вы такое реализовывали? приходилось?

Comment: я вообще kohana в глаза не видел, поэтому могу только алгоритм описать )

Comment: Fike дело говорит. Только я бы ещё прикрутил JS обработчик, который меняет uri, чтобы этой ссылкой можно было поделиться.

Comment: да,он прав, просто у меня с Kohana не получается это реализовать